# Protocol implementation method not calling in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Xcode 10.3. I have protocol which method is not calling. What is wrong?

My first view controller with protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
   func doGetUpdateInfo(valu1:String,value2:String);
}

class Class_A : UIViewController{
    weak var myprotocolDelegate:MyProtocol? = nil;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myprotocolDelegate?.doGetUpdateInfo(account_no:value1, account_title: value2)
    }
}
```

My second view controller

```
class Class_B: UIViewController,UpdateBeneficiaryProtocol {
    var class_a = Class_A()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        class_a.myprotocolDelegate = self;
    }

    func doGetUpdateInfo(value1: String, value2: String) {
        print("not calling****")
    }
}
```

What is the wrong with it?

Comment: The delegate only gets called if `Class_A` gets presented as a view controller. Did you present `Class_A` at all?

Comment: @Sweeper  I have open custom dialog based on view controller of class_B

Comment: Which class is the custom dialog? If it is class B, then you've got the delegate the wrong way around.

Comment: @Sweeper class_B is used for custom class

Comment: @Sweeper class_B is used custom dialog pop up over class_A. How to used delegate if it wrong. Can you tell me please?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below example. you are creating a new class for A but so it will not be called. you need to provide a reference for the current class

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
 func doGetUpdateInfo(valu1:String,value2:String);
}

class Class_A : UIViewController{
weak var myprotocolDelegate:MyProtocol? = nil;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myprotocolDelegate?.doGetUpdateInfo(account_no:value1, account_title: value2)
}
func navigateToClassB() {
     let classb = Class_B() 
     classb.class_a = self
     self.navigationController?.pushViewcontroller(classb, animated:true)
}
 }
```

And class b should be

```
class Class_B: UIViewController,UpdateBeneficiaryProtocol {
var class_a : Class_A?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    class_a.myprotocolDelegate = self;
}

func doGetUpdateInfo(value1: String, value2: String) {
    print("not calling****")
}
}
```

Push controller Class_b as per display in method navigateToClassB.
If you face still issue comment here I will assist you.

Comment: Also: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/